# How to add Custom Validations for React Material UI controls?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using ReactJs in an application and I need to add validation against my all fields.

I want add validation against name, phone number, email, password and confirm password.

When anyone 'll enter some invalid data in these fields, validation messages should be displayed with fields.

```
import React from 'react';   
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  }
}));

export default function RegisterForm() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">        
      <div className={classes.paper}>        
        <form >
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="name"
                name="name"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                error
                fullWidth
                id="name"
                label="Name"
                autoFocus
              />
            </Grid>           
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
              />
            </Grid>            
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="password"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="repeatpassword"
                label="Repeat Password"
                type="password"
                id="repeatpassword"
                autoComplete="repeat-password"
              />
            </Grid>           
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Create
          </Button>         
        </form>
      </div>    
    </Container>
  );
}
```

I'm a newbie with react. What should I do in my code?

I've grabbed the example code for a menus and cards from here: https://material-ui.com

```
Application built with
{
  "react": "16.13.0", 
  "react-dom": "^16.13.0", 
  "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
  "redux": "^4.0.4"
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5"
}
```

The problem i face is getting an error in following function:

```
<TextField
                    autoComplete="name"
                    name="name"
                    variant="outlined"
                    required
                    error
                    fullWidth
                    id="name"
                    label="Name"
                    autoFocus
                  />
```

above Textfield is displaying the required validation error on form submit but this is not what i am trying to implement. I want to customize the validations and validation messages for email, confirm email, phone number, password and confirm password as per recommended approach.

I tried to follow guides and looked up example implementations but could not find the recommended way to solve the the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using [formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik) and [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) to achieve similar things in my apps. Here is a simple example how to mix it together:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ol11mmk30z